# Issues configuring SAML authentication in Apache Guacamole behind a HAProxy

Tags: haproxy, single-sign-on, saml

I've deployed an Apache Guacamole server and trying to configure SSO using SAML with a Cloud IdaaS. HAproxy is in front of the Guacamole server, providing SSL offloading. Apache Guacamole was configured following the tutorial on the Guacamole website.

When I attempt to authenticate using SAML, I am finding myself in a redirect loop. The following message is showing up in the Tomcat logs:

```
03:45:29.364 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] WARN  o.a.g.a.s.a.AssertionConsumerServiceResource - Authentication attempted with an invalid SAML response: SAML response did not pass validation: The response was received at http://my.personal.domain/guacamole/api/ext/saml/callback instead of https://my.personal.domain/guacamole/api/ext/saml/callback
```

I've checked the setting in the IdP and confirmed that everything is indeed configured for HTTPS. I wonder if the issue has something to do with traffic between HAProxy and Guacamole being HTTP, but I don't know how or what to do to change that. I'm happy to use a self-signed certificate between HAProxy and Guacamole since they are both on a protected network.

Any ideas you could share would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this myself by switching Tomcat over to SSL.